# Php file upload returns false

Tags: php, image, file

I am trying to upload an image. The code part about uploading image is taken from w3school.But when code comes to if, it returns false and doesn't give an error. The code is:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '500M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 4000); // Play with the values
ini_set('max_execution_time', 4000); // Play with the values
print_r($_FILES);
$target_dir = "uploads/";
@$topic = htmlspecialchars($_POST["topic"]);
@$textarea = htmlspecialchars($_POST["textarea"]);
try {
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_input"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$_FILES["file_input"]["name"])){
       echo "upload succesfull";
   }else{
       echo"upload failed";
   }
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is a file whose name is file_operations.php. There is a file whose name is file_form.php. file_form.php has a form and in the form there is an input html tag whose type is file. Form's action is file_operations.php. "***if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_input"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$_FILES["file_input"]["name"]))***" returns false. My form is:

```
<form action="save_operations.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name='topic' class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Topic">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Textarea</label>
    <textarea name='textarea' class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
    <input name='file' type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" placeholder="Submit">
```

Comment: Please also share the form.

Comment: Where exactly did you find this code? It's terrible. It doesn't even check the upload result code in `$_FILES` and assumes that `move_uploaded_file()` throws exceptions.

Comment: Have you got a succession for php image or file upload ?